# How to add custom tablecell collection to gridview row

Tags: asp.net, gridview, gridviewrow

I've created a custom GridView server control.  The next thing I'd like to do is to use my own custom TableCell Collection with that GridView so I can set some custom properties and etc.  Countless hours of Google searches have made me dizzy and yielded no real results.

Does anyone have any tips on how to accomplish integrating a custom TableCell Collection into the GridView's GridViewRow?

Comment: Have you also created a class that inherits from TableCell class? By this, you can add your TableCell object to GridViewRow.

Answer (score 0):

Does your custom GridView control extend the built-in GridView?

If so, it should be possible to use your custom TableCell in your GridView's RenderContents function.

If you'd like, please post any of your code that might help. I've worked on custom GridViews before (albeit with very limited functionality), so I might be able to lend a hand.